# how to fix EXT2-fs (sda1): error: ext2_lookup deleted inode referenced XXXX

Tags: linux

Some time ago I installed Kubuntu 12.10 on Acer TravelMate 8572G which has Linpus LiveCD Editon v9.2 installed. When I tried to remove Kubuntu, something went wrong and I ended up with a broken Grub. Then I repaired it with Boot Disk Repair but before Linpus loads, I can see plenty of lines of errors like this:

`EXT2-fs (sda1): error: ext2_lookup deleted inode referenced XXXX`

How can I get rid of them? I don't want to install any other system, just left the laptop as it is with Linpus (I borrowed the laptop to do some things)

Comment: I'm not sure, but sometimes things like these are easily solved by a `e2fsck -f /dev/sda1` (with sda1 unmounted).

Comment: Complementing Teresa's remark: This usually means booting from a live / rescue medium. In order to avoid this need I always install a second, small service Linux which is accessible from a static boot manager configuration.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior thank you, it helped! Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: @rrh you're welcome! I have posted an answer.

Comment: related http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191370/ext4-lookup-deleted-inode-referenced-error-in-var-log-messages

Answer (score 4):

Problems with deleted inodes generally can be solved with simply a filesystem check on the device *umounted*:

```
e2fsck -f /dev/sda1
```

As Hauke said, the easiest way to perform checks on umounted filesystems is through a Live medium.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use:

```
fsck.ext2 /dev/sda1
```

which is a specie of alias to `e2fsck` to e2fsck write completion information to the standard input (file descriptor 0), so that the progress of the filesystem check can be monitored.

> fsck.ext2 will print a completion bar as it goes about its business.

From man pages