# "ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced" error in /var/log/messages

Tags: linux, logs

I checked my /var/log/messages log file, on every 2 secs interval there is some log getting added..

```
Mar 20 11:42:30 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 184844
Mar 20 11:42:32 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 184844
Mar 20 11:42:34 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 184844
Mar 20 11:42:36 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 184844
Mar 20 11:42:38 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 184844
Mar 20 11:42:40 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 184844
Mar 20 11:42:42 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 184844
Mar 20 11:42:44 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 184844
```

I didn't do any kind of operation on the system, but still error is getting logged. I suppose FS is corrupted.

What should I do?

Comment: `umount` and `fsck` the filesystem would be my suggestion...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am sharing the answer, as how I resolved this issue.

I edited the /etc/fstab and provided the root FS with FSCK=1,

```
/dev/mapper/vg_vipin-lv_root /   ext4    defaults        0 1
```

And then I did a reboot.

fsck will be performed and now everything is back to normal.

Comment: What do you mean "provided" FS with FSCK=1. Using what command and typed where?

Comment: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html
FSCK setting is on the sixth field, so changing the last "0" to "1" will trigger fsck on boot

Answer (score 16):

I encountered this error before as well. A manual file system check fixes it, but you can consider some files lost already.

Syntax:

```
fsck -y
```

It is best to do this in single user mode.

Comment: Why should the `fsck` perform best in single user mode, Wbruan?